# My Python 3.4.2 program will only round to 15 decimal places, even when I use the round() function to tell it to round to more

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program to approximate the golden ratio to the largest amount of precision possible. It works, but when I tell it to round to more than 16 decimal places, it just doesn't go past 15. This is my code:

```
# Using fractions to approximate the Golden Ratio

a = 1
b = 1
while b < 1000000000000000:
    g = a + b
    h = g / a
    print (round(h, 20))
    b = a
    a = g
```

I realize that the while loop probably isn't the best way to do this, so if there is a more efficient way, please inform me of that. But my main question is is this rounding issue fixable? Or will I just have to settle for 15 decimal places? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[`float` doesn't have more than about 15 actual decimal places. Rounding it to more is pointless, since they don't exist.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

- If you really care about precision, I believe you should be using [Decimal numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead of integers and floats.
- Regardless of the type you use, be sure that you are [formatting your string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) the way you want, and not just using print's default.